# QTest::qExec Hide "passed" messages

Tags: c++, qt, qtestlib

I'm new in Qt and QTest. I use QTest::qExec(&someMyTestClassObject) to run my tests. 
Is possible to hide "PASS   : MyClass::myTest" messages? Of course i want to see all "FAIL" messages and statistics
Sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it works with `QTest::qexec`, but with the default QTest executable generated with `QTEST_APPLESS_MAIN(MyTestClass)` you can run tests with the parameter `-silent`.

From the help-text:

```
-silent    : Only outputs warnings and failures
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! But when i trying     
    QStringList l;
    l.append("-silent");
    QTest::qExec(&tests, l);
"PASS" Messages still showing

Comment: try adding an empty string as first argument:  QStringList l; l.append(""); l.append("-silent");

Comment: I confirm, adding an empty string as first argument works and it does limit the output. Thanks!